# SQLAlchemy trusted connection with different windows username/password than local user - Python

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, connection-string, pyodbc

I am trying to connect to a sql server with a different username/password combination than on my local account. I know it is valid credentials, since i am able to login through SSMS.

I've tried the following:

```
connection_string = "DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=server;DATABASE=db;UID=username;PWD=password"
connection_url = URL.create("mssql", query={"odbc_connect": connection_string})
```

Where i get the login failed response:
`[SQL Server]Login failed for user 'username'. (18456)`

I am trying to connect to a microsoft sql server (on the same network)

Answer (score 0):

You get the error, because the Windows account don't have permissions to logon to SQL Server. Note: Windows admin <> SQL admin, it has it's own permission system.
Grant logon and other required permissions for the Windows logon.

According to your error code I guess. "Using Windows login name with SQL Server authentication"

Comment: I am able to login through ssms, so i know the account has permission to logon to the sql server. I can do it manually. I am trying to figure out how to make sqlAlchemy login with different windows credentials than the local account.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use Windows Authentication with sqlalchemy and mssql, the following connection string is required:

ODBC Driver:

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mssql://*server_name*/*database_name*?trusted_connection=yes')
```

SQL Express Instance:

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mssql://*server_name*\\SQLEXPRESS/*database_name*?trusted_connection=yes')
```

Try

Comment: Yes, this also work on my local account. But i am trying to connect with a different windows account. I need to login through windows authentication with a different account than the python script is running on.